# jQuery UI Datepicker localization error on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, localization, datepicker

I'm trying to include the jQuery UI datepicker with a default locale using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["it"]);
    $('#div-where-place-datepicker').datepicker({
        "dateFormat": "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
```

According to [docs](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline) I'm adding it to a div so the datepicker is shown inline on page load (like a calendar).

The problem is that after page load the calendar is not localized (english texts) and after I interact with it it loads the localization (it becomes italian).

Any fix for this?

Comment: maybe just a cache issue?

Comment: I've cleared the cache and tested it on FF and Chrome and the behavior is the same.

Comment: do you load the localization file from an external uri?

Comment: somewhat related to what @clph3r just stated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452681/jquery-datepicker-localization

Comment: can you post your html-head section too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found where is the problem and fixed it :)

I'm including the scripts (including the localization i18n) in the footer for a faster page load (after my init script) so I've moved the scripts in the header (before my init script) and now the localization is loaded on first execution.

Comment: Actually, I had a very similar problem: I was loading the language specific javascript file after setting my calendar to use it. I could keep it in the footer, though ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try setting the defaults after you've created the datepicker instance.

The other option might be to try setting the localization of that specific instance when you create it vs setting the default then creating it.
Per jquery UI docs

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

Comment: Same behavior with "$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["it"]);" before, after and before+after .datepicker() init.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
My solution was to not wrap the datepicker function within an anonymous function.

```
//jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['de'] = {...};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
//});
```