# Translate date function output string in other language using jquery/js?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-format

Is there way to translate output of date function string in other language using jquery/js?

Actually I want to translate month string in other language(German, Spanish, French etc.).

**Snap**

[image]

**For Example:**

```
var D =  jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd yy', new Date());
alert(D);
```

**Output In English:** June 21 2013

But I want date format output in **other languages**, like as:

```
French: juin 21 2013

German: Juni 21 2013

Spanish: junio 21 2013

Portuguese: junho 21 2013
```

Am unable to get how do I translate month name in other language?

I found solution in **PHP**( `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'language_name'); strftime(format sting);` ) but I need it in **jQuery or JS**?

So guys, you could suggest me a better solution.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  Your answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1865228/870729

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452681/jquery-datepicker-localization

Comment: @cale_b I want output string translation not for calendar-langauage, dude.

Comment: I am also facing same issue? Is there any solution u got@Frank

Comment: @hvs9 there are some language files come with this PHP Date Picker package, so we need to pass localization extension of the language which you want to load on fronted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Frank, actually I am using Java as backend, and I wanted to fix it via Javascript. I wrote some line of code to overcome this issue. :)

Comment: @hvs9 If you are using a jQuery Date Picker then please refer this link https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization