# Jquery datepicker localized alt format for alt field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this fun datepicker in my french page :

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
}, $.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
```

Problem is that my "#alternate" input get's the date formated correctly but doesn't take the regionnal setting. And so dates show up in english instead of french.

How can I configure the plugin to setup dates in the altField respecting my widget's regional setting?

Thanks!

Comment: Does you have a look at the documentation for [`datepicker`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? It has a section there regarding regional formatting.

Comment: @kel yeah that's where I got the regional config in. That part works for the calendar UI portion. But as I use my altField, the date printed in there as I pick a date in the widget is not affected by my regional setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either set the localization beforehand via `setDefaults` or afterward with jQuery UI's option format.

**Example One:**

```
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  altField: "#alternate",
  altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

**Example Two:**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  altField: "#alternate",
  altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", $.datepicker.regional['fr'] );
```

[Live Example](http://codepen.io/neagle/pen/gAEqL)

Either way works for both the primary datepicker and the alternate field.

Answer (score 0):

Found it here!

[jQuery Datepicker localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452681/jquery-datepicker-localization)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker($.extend({
        altField: "#alternate",
        altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
    },
    $.datepicker.regional['fr']
));
```