# How to set properly localisation for datepicker in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js, datepicker

I put `locale: en` in my options, but that doesnt work.
Should I put somewhere else?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        var options = {
            format: 'MM d, yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            maxDate: 0,
            language: 'en'
        };
                
        //console.log("datepicker");
        $(element).datepicker(options);
              
        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });
    }
};
```

Im using jquery-ui 1.10.4

Comment: If you're using jQueryUI's datepicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: @DVN-Anakin yes, but maybe I can put just arrays for days, months in my binding section? something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452681/jquery-datepicker-localization